# Excel: Grouping and restructuring data in Excel

Tags: excel

In Excel, I want to convert the table on the top (Initial data) into the one at the bottom (Desired output).
I want to group the items in the second row by the first row, and then generate one column per unique value of the first row and list the items of the corresponding group in that column.

Is there a way to do that without manually copying cells?

**Table: Initial data**

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Fruit | Banana |
| Fruit | Apple |
| Fruit | Grape |
| Vegetable | Spinach |
| Vegetable | Eggplant |

**Table: Desired output**

| Fruit | Vegetable |
| --- | --- |
| Banane | Spinach |
| Apple | Eggplant |
| Grape |  |

Comment: Yes, there is.  You can use formulas (easiest in Office 365), VBA and/or Power Query. I suggest you post what you have tried, and indicate where your approach has given you problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the `UNIQUE` and `FILTER` functions (Excel 365), you could accomplish this as follows.

Assuming your data is in `A1:B5`. In `D1` enter:

```
=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE($A$1:$A$5))
```

This will get you the unique values from the cells in `A` in `D1:E1`. Then in `D2` enter:

```
=FILTER($B$1:$B$5,$A$1:$A$5=D1)
```

And drag to the right.

I.e. you do this:

[image: formulas transpose]

Result:

[image: result]